# Помогите с питоном, попалась непонятная задача

Tags: python

У меня есть такая задача - нужен код, который при запуске будет проверять наличие обновления у определенных **установленных** программ (Putty и R7 офис), в случае необходимости обновиться предлагал сделать это и обновлял. Если кто то хотя бы примерно знает как это сделать, то очень прошу ответить сразу с примерным алгоритмом работы программы или с библиотеками!

Comment: все действия производятся на винде

Answer (score 2):

Ну декомпозируйте задачу.

1. Получить как-то номера версий установленных программ.
2. Посмотреть, какие версии лежат на сайтах этих программ.
3. Если версии новее, то сказать, что есть обновление и предложить установить.
4. Если пользователь согласен, то скачать новые версии и запустить установщики.

Это общий план. А дальше по пунктам разбирайтесь, как и что сделать. Стандартных средств особо нет вроде бы, всё кустарно делать придётся.

Comment: Я бы 0 пунктом вписал - *понять, в какой ОС все эти действия производить* :)

Comment: @АлексейР, putty бывает где-то кроме Windows?

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy "Изначально разрабатывался для Microsoft Windows, однако позднее портирован на Unix. В разработке находятся порты для Mac OS и macOS. Сторонние разработчики выпустили неофициальные порты на другие платформы: мобильные телефоны под управлением Symbian OS, коммуникаторы с Windows Mobile, а также устройства с iOS и Android."

Comment: @АлексейР, но зачем? Везде есть терминалы и SSH. И только на Windows нет ни того ни другого.

Comment: https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/faq.html#faq-unix-why